# Smoothing spline/raster in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, smoothing, arcglobe

I have a spline, but it turned out to be angular at the ends, is there a tool or how can I smooth the raster in ArcGIS?

[image]

Comment: Hi @easyfreeze, welcome to GIS SE. Which version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: yes, I have access to the Spatial analyst tool

Comment: Excellent, you should look into the "Generalization toolset", I've provided details in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to achieve what you are looking for by using [Smoothing zone edges with Boundary Clean and Majority Filter](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/smoothing-zone-edges-with-boundary-clean-and-majority-filter.htm)

> The Boundary Clean and Majority Filter tools are used to generalize the edges of zones in a raster. The edges are smoothed to varying degrees either by expanding and shrinking boundaries or by growing or shrinking zones based on the values within the neighborhood of individual locations.

> In the image below, Boundary Clean was applied to the input raster with no sorting of the zones. Zones with larger values have a higher priority to expand into zones with smaller values. Notice that cells with the value 7 expand into the lower value cells.

[image]

> In the image below, Majority Filter is applied to the input raster using a filter of the closest four cells, which are the four orthogonal neighboring cells, requiring the majority (three out of four cells) to be the same before a cell will change its value. Only those cells surrounded by three or more (orthogonal) cells with the same value are changed.

[image]

Comment: couldn't smooth out the corners of the raster((

Comment: Can you update your original post with any screenshots of your results, inputs?

Comment: added an image, the raster looks angular at the corners.